# Query String (URL) Filter for Search Result?

Tags: 2013, search-results, filter

How to activate a Query String (URL) Filter for Search Result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better method is to use the keyboard filter rather than a Query String (URL) Filter ([this link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj683123%28v=office.15%29.aspx)).

1. Verify that the user account that performs this procedure is a
   member of the Designers SharePoint group on the Enterprise Search
   Center site.
2. On the search results page, click the Settings menu, and then click
   Edit Page.
3. In the Search Results Web Part, click the Search Results Web Part
   Menu arrow, and then click Edit Web Part.
4. In the Web Part tool pane, in the Search Criteria section, click
   Change query.
5. On the keyboard filter, select the Value of a parameter from URL.
6. then, Add keyword filter.